# PHP: How to get URL of relative file

Tags: php, url, relative-path

Does PHP have a native function that returns the full URL of a file you declare with a relative path? I need to get: `"http://www.domain.com/projects/test/img/share.jpg"` from `"img/share.jpg"` So far I've tried the following:

```
realpath('img/share.jpg');
// Returns "/home/user/www.domain.com/projects/test/img/share.jpg"
```

I also tried:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
// Returns "/home/user/www.domain.com/projects/test"
```

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php) states that the following can be tampered with client-side:

```
"http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI].'img/share.jpg"
```

plus, my path will vary depending on whether I'm accessing from `/test/index.php` or just `test/` without index.php and I don't want to hard-code whether it's http or https.

Does anybody have a solution for this? I'll be sending these files to another person who will upload to their server, so the folder structure will not match `"/home/user/www.domain.com/"`

Comment: you can add an answer and accept it also you get reps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace(preg_quote($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']), 'http://www.example.com/', realpath('img/share.jpg'), 1);
```

Docs: [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

The arguments of `preg_replace`:

- `preg_quote($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` - Takes the document root (e.g., `/home/user/www.domain.com/`) and makes it a regular expression for use with `preg_replace`.
- `'http://www.example.com/'` - the string to replace the regex match with.
- `realpath('img/share.jpg')` - the string for the file path including the document root.
- `1` - the number of times to replace regex matches.

Comment: Thanks! But I'd like to avoid this because I'm sending the files to another person who will upload to their own server, and I doubt that their folder structure will start with `/home/user/`

Comment: Unfortunately, preq_replace kept giving me the following error: `Unknown modifier 'n' in...` 
After some digging, this is the code that worked: `echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], 'http://www.domain.com', realpath('img/share.jpg'));`
Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
echo preg_replace("'". preg_quote($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ."'",'http://www.example.com/', realpath('img/share.jpg'), 1);
```