# Get URL of the current file with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, url, dirname

I have a PHP Class written for use in WordPress themes or plugins that loads some JS and CSS using `enqueue_script` and `enqueue_style` when the Class is initialized.

I need to dynamically get the URL (not the absolute path) to the directory the Class is being loaded so I can pass this URL to `enqueue_script` and `enqueue_style` for asset loading.

**Directory Structure** 

`wp-content
├── themes
│   ├── theme_name
│   │   ├── my_class
│   │   │   ├── my_class.php
│   │   │   ├── js  (need URL)
│   │   │   │   ├── file.js*
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   ├── file.css*`

Is there a PHP function that works like `[dirname][1]` but returns a file URL not a path?

**EDIT**
The `my_class` directory should be able to be dropped anywhere, in a theme or plugin, so I can't rely on WordPress core functions to get the URL to the class dir.

Comment: An example of what you want to get? What have you tried? You would probably want to check [get_site_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/)... something like `$file_relative_path = "..."; $url = get_site_url(null, $file_relative_path, 'https');`?

Comment: This can be used in a theme or plugin, so get_site_url doesn't work. The class directory should be able to be dropped anywhere, so I can't rely on WordPress core functions.

Answer (score 5):

`__DIR__` will give you the file path to the folder of the current script and then you can simply remove your document root (the path to the folder your files are hosted out of) and then you are left with the url path:

```
$file_path = __DIR__;
$url_path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $file_path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working in WordPress, the WordPress-specific way of doing this is to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. It will return the URL for the current theme (or child theme). See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/ for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution from this url:

[PHP: How to get URL of relative file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390829/php-how-to-get-url-of-relative-file)

But instead of using `preg_replace` try using `str_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue and I made my own solution. If anyone still needs the answer, here it is.

If you're sure the class will be in a plugin or theme, you can use the WP_CONTENT_URL and WP_CONTENT_DIR constants, along with __DIR__, to find the URL of the current working directory. Just replace WP_CONTENT_DIR with WP_CONTENT_URL in __DIR__ and you're all set.

```
function getCurrentDirUrl(){
   return str_replace(WP_CONTENT_DIR,WP_CONTENT_URL,__DIR__);
}
```